# How do you find the largest/smallest number amongst several array's?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to get the largest/smallest number returned out of two or more `numpy.array` of equal length. Since `max()/min()` function doesn't work on multiple arrays, this is some of the best(worst) I've come up with:

`max(max(a1), max(a2), max(a3), ...) / min(min(a1), min(a2), min(a3), ...)`

Alternately one can use numpy's maximum, but those only work for two arrays at time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Suppose `a1 = array([1, 2])` and `a2 = array([0, 3])`. For the minimum, do you want `0`? `array([0, 2])`? Something else? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to get max valued element. Consider `a1 = ([0,1]); a2 = ([1, 2]); a3 = ([2, 3])`, then i want 3 returned, but in my case i don't know the numbers in the arrays, only that their lengths are equal!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is linear time and works with Numpy arrays

```
>>> import itertools
>>> max(itertools.chain([1,2,3],[1,2,4],[-1, -2, 5])

5
```

Answer (score 0):

> max()/min() function doesn't work on multiple arrays

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) will work on an array of arrays, then return a single array, which you can then find the `max` or `min` of that array.

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = [3,4,1]
>>> l3 = [6,1,8]
>>> map(max, [l1, l2, l3])
[3, 4, 8]
>>> max(map(max, [l1, l2, l3]))
8
```

Comment: We're working with NumPy arrays, not Python built-in lists. Python's built-in `max` is inefficient on them, and it won't even work on multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @user2357112 - OP said "alternatively" - does not imply numpy was used for the initial lists

Comment: `max(numpy.max(a for a in [l1, l2 ,l3])` would have `numpy.max` work on the numpy arrays and the built-in `max` work through a generator. This should be sufficiently efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Combine your arrays into one, then take the min/max along the new axis.

`A = np.array([a1,a2, ... , an])
A.min(axis=0), A.max(axis=0)`

Comment: there is no need to combine (which  makes multiple copies) before computing max()

Comment: Combining makes a single copy; it would be nice if we could avoid that, but numpy tends to force you to make such tradeoffs between efficiency and clarity. Yes, you could implement this more efficiently in C; but performance-wise you are not going to be able to beat it in python. So yes, there is a need to combine; and that is because this is necessary before we can use the tried-and-true min/max functions. The real question is why these related arrays of identical length were not placed in a single array earlier.

Comment: It wasn't possible since i  needed to take some `str` arguments from `cml`, convert to `float` and then process it through several functions which evidently ended up in some arrays of x coordinates and finally those arrays i asked about - y coordinates for plotting :)